# Django SQL syntax error when using two different database engines

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use django with multiple databases. One default postgres-db and another mysql-db. I followed the documentation on how to configure both dbs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/

My settings.py looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "default",
        "USER": "----------",
        "PASSWORD": "-----------",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432",
    },
    "data": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "NAME": "data",
        "USER": "---------",
        "PASSWORD": "---------",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "3306",
    }
}
```

Things work fine when querying the default database. But it seems that django uses postgres-db sql syntax for queries on the mysql-db:

```
# Model "Test" lives in the mysql-db.
Test.objects.using('data').all()

# gives me the following exception

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ERROR:  SyntaxError at ».«
LINE 1: EXPLAIN SELECT `test`.`id`, `test`.`title`, ...
```

It even uses the postgres-db client psycopg2 to generate/execute it.

Using a raw query works fine though, this means it does correctly use the mysql-db for the specific query.

```
Test.objects.using('data').raw('SELECT * FROM test')
# works
```

How can i configure Django to use the correct SQL syntax when using multiple databases of different engines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with mssql & oracle. Django generates query with "[" & "]" symbols for Oracle DB. The only thing I came up with is to use

```
MyModel.objects.raw(m.query.__str__().replace('[', '"').replace(']', '"'))
```